# list() function of Python modifies its argument?

Tags: python

(I am quite a newbie in Python, so lots of things puzzle me even after reading the tutorial...)

Initially, I had the code like the following:

```
strings = ['>abc', 'qwertyu', '>def', 'zxcvbnm']
matrix  = zip(*strings)
for member in matrix:
    print("".join(member)) # characters are printed as expected
```

-- which did what I expected. But then for some reason I wanted to determine the number of members in matrix; as len(matrix) gave an error, I decided to copy it with converting to the list: `mtxlist = list(matrix)`. Surprisingly, after this line the content of matrix seems to be changed - or at least I cannot use it the same way as above:

```
strings = ['>abc', 'qwertyu', '>def', 'zxcvbnm']
matrix  = zip(*strings)
mtxlist = list(matrix) # this assignment empties (?) the matrix
for member in matrix:
    print("".join(member)) # nothing printed
```

Can anybody explain what is going on there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using Python 3, correct?

`zip` returns a generator that can only be iterated once. If you want to use it more than once, then your options are:

Write `zip(*strings)` each time you need it.

```
matrix = tuple(zip(*strings))
```

(iterate `matrix` as many times as you like. This is the easy option. The downside is that if `zip(*strings)` is big then it uses a lot of memory that the generator doesn't.)

```
matrix1, matrix2 = itertools.tee(zip(*strings))
```

(iterate each of `matrix1` and `matrix2` once. This is worse than the `tuple` in your usage, but it's useful if you want to partially consume `matrix1`, then use some of `matrix2`, more of `matrix1`, etc)

```
def matrix():
    return zip(*strings)
# or
matrix = lambda: zip(*strings)
```

(iterate but using `matrix()`, not `matrix`, as many times as you like. Doesn't use extra memory for a copy of the result like the `tuple` solution, but the syntax for using it is a bit annoying)

```
class ReusableIterable:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.func())

matrix = ReusableIterable(lambda: zip(*strings))
```

(iterate using `matrix` as many times as you like. Deals with the syntax annoyance, although you still have to beware that if you modify `strings` between iterations over `matrix` then you'll get different results.)

Comment: now I start to understand, thanks a lot! (yes, I am using Python 3.3). Unfortunately I couldn't find much details about such dynamic behavior in standard library at docs.python.org - probably there's some better source to read... 
Now I see that my title is not really correct as this case has nothing to do with `list()` itself

Comment: @VasilyA: I think you're OK. It kind of does have to do with `list`, and `list` is the case you encountered it with. But *any* callable, including `list`, that iterates over something will modify that thing if the thing is a one-use generator.

Comment: As for documentation: http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip says that it returns an "iterator". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/ explains the difference between an *iterator* and an *iterable*. So the documentation tells you what you need to know, but only if you understand the jargon. http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types documents the jargon, but perhaps doesn't make the difference as clear as it might be. There's probably more on the subject in the official tutorial.

Comment: great, with these additional links things are much more clear. Thanks!